# How to fix black screen when starting a new fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

Black screen appears short time while starting fragment. I will do a barcode scan on the fragment.

If I just open a blank screen, I do not see the black screen. I think the problem I'm about to open is that the fragment loading time is long.

How can I solve this problem

My code

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,newFragment2())
                .commit();


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView
        android:id="@+id/qrdecoderview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you set the layout of Fragment ? If Yes then post code here .Then only someone can help .

Comment: Where is your code? No code, no help

Comment: sorry. I added the code

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to load the QRCodeReaderView programmatically after onCreate() or PostCreate()? Or you can try doing it asynchronously once the fragment is fully loaded.

Comment: I've tried. But again a black screen appears for a short time.

Comment: Is the problem happening with others fragments as well?

Comment: no only on camera page. I guess the page comes up when it gets late

Answer (score 0):

If QRCodeReaderView or any other view delays the fragment initialisation, you may try using [ViewStubs.](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html)

From Android Docs,

> A ViewStub is an invisible, zero-sized View that can be used to lazily
>   inflate layout resources at runtime. When a ViewStub is made visible,
>   or when inflate() is invoked, the layout resource is inflated. The
>   ViewStub then replaces itself in its parent with the inflated View or
>   Views. Therefore, the ViewStub exists in the view hierarchy until
>   setVisibility(int) or inflate() is invoked. The inflated View is added
>   to the ViewStub's parent with the ViewStub's layout parameters